# How do I set default material properties in Blender?

Tags: materials, normals, normal-map

I have a large collection of models that I import into Blender.  When I import it, for each material zone, I have to do the following:

1. Select 'Normal Map' for normals
2. Select 'Image Texture' for normals color
3. Open and select the normals map
4. Select 'Image Texture' for base color
5. Open and select the diffuse map
6. Set specular to 0

This gets beyond tedious.  Is there a way to set steps 1,2,4,and 6 above to be the default whenever I add a new material slot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a material that has all of the nodes you want.  Call it something like "baseline" or "default material".  Select the "fake user" shield, so that Blender won't delete it.

Now, for each model, select the default material, and click the button to make a copy.  Rename the copy appropriately. Select each image texture in turn and change the image by clicking on the folder icon and using the file browser.

Comment: Fantastic.  You have saved me tons of tedious work.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.